# Where to Change BOBs in Montreal?

Tags: money, exchange, montreal

Going through leftover foreign currency, I found several where I had enough to make the amount non-trivial. I managed to change  every currency except for the Bolivian Boliviano. Even went to TD Foreign Exchange branch that offers over 70 currencies but BOB was not one of them. They are mostly large bill, no coins as exchanges never accept those.

**Where can I change BOB currency to Canadian dollars in Montreal?** Towards the west side of town or downtown is easier, if there are multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Globex 2000](https://www.globex2000.ca) has several locations in Montreal and accepts BOBs as well as a huge list of currencies. One has to create an account with them which takes about a minute and then you can proceed with exchanging currencies, including Bolivian Bolivianos.